# Prove that $\max\{|ac+b|,|a+bc|\}\ge\frac{mn}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers such that $|a+b|=m$ and $|a-b|=n$ and $mn\ne0$. Prove that
>   $$\max\{|ac+b|,|a+bc|\}\ge\frac{mn}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$$

I have tried using formula
$$\max\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$$
Let $A=\max\{|ac+b|,|a+bc|\}$, then
$$A=\frac{|ac+b|+|a+bc|+||ac+b|-|a+bc||}{2}$$
Then I have used triangle inequality:
$$A\ge\frac{|ac+b+a+bc|+||ac+b|-|a+bc||}{2}$$
But, I don't know how to simplify it. Also, is it possible to apply some inequality to $||ac+b|-|a+bc||$?

Comment: I'm trying to think about the geometric interpretation of this. If a and b are sides of a parallelogram, then m and n are the lengths of the diagonals. So $\frac {mn} 2$ is the largest possible area of the parallelogram... Does $\frac {mn} 2 \le$ area help?

Comment: @tomi I have alrady came to that idea, but I dont know what to do with $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question about $||ac+b|-|a+bc||$, there is the inequality
$$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|.$$

But I dont see how you are using that $mn\neq 0$. So what can you conclude from $mn\neq0$? It means you can divide by it, and $a\neq \pm b$. See if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: I have checked all these options and tried many other ways to solve it. I know that formula, but it cannot help me, because I need to get $A\ge$something, instead of $A\le$something.

Comment: You can always start looking at the other side; that is, manipulate the RHS to get its less than the LHS. Or you can try to divide both sides by $mn$ because its non-zero. Just some options.

Comment: I have already checked all that options.

Answer (score 0):

PUF!…It is not true for general c and reals. Making |a+b| = a+b and |a-b| = a-b then for a+bc, say, being the max we would have

[image]

what is impossible for arbitrary c. Or am I wrong?

NOTE: I have put |a+bc| = a+bc but does not matter if a+bc < 0 because always you find an arbitrary real c bounded (up or low) by a constant.

Comment: Not sure where and how, but you are surely wrong. The question is correct and I actually saw a proof of my proffesor, but It is extremely complicated and I cannot understand it, so I cannot tell why your approach is wrong, just believe me it is wrong.